Java Apache Wicket AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior - avoiding web browser memory bloat/leak?
I am using the Apache Java WicketStuff InMethod grid and wanted the grid to automatically refresh its contents at 1-second intervals - the window can stay open for several hours at a time. So I attached an AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehaviour to the grid as shown below. The grid does indeed update correctly however after some time (~15mins) Google Chrome crashes with an out of memory exception. Profiling the browser does indeed show the Chrome tab memory growing incrementally with each update (like a leak).
Is this expected behaviour? Am I misusing the Ajax functionality here? Should I be using something else WebSockets? for this use case?
I experimented with adding some HTML <head> meta refresh to force a page refresh every 2 minutes but this workaround smells to me.
Thanks in advance!
import com.inmethod.grid.IDataSource;
import com.inmethod.grid.datagrid.DataGrid;
import com.inmethod.grid.datagrid.DefaultDataGrid;

DataGrid<IDataSource<MyRow>, MyRow, String> myGrid = new DefaultDataGrid<IDataSource<MyRow>, MyRow, String>("myGrid", myDataSource,myColumns);

myGrid.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)));

